# How to add z-index jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

I have this:

```
jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css('background-color','#ddf8dd')
```

How do I correctly add z-index:200?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass an object to the [`.css()`](http://jquery%20css%20method%20not%20working) method, i.e.:

```
jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css({
    'background-color': '#ddf8dd',
    'z-index': 200
});
```

Note that the `z-index` has to be wrapped in single quotes, otherwise JS will interpret the `-` as a mathematical minus/subtraction operator. Of course, you can always write the keys using camelCase, i.e.:

```
jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css({
    backgroundColor: '#ddf8dd',
    zIndex: 200
});
```

---

If you want to assign the z-index in a separate line, you can do this:

```
jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css('background-color', '#ddf8dd');
jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css('z-index, 200);
```

Not very efficient or pretty though, there's a lot of bloat. You can cache the selector instead:

```
var $el = jQuery('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr');
$el.css('background-color', '#ddf8dd');

// Some lines later
$el.css('z-index', 200);
```

Comment: looks like I need to keep this format -> .css('background-color','#ddf8dd')

Comment: @user3903810 Why so? There is no reason why you can't pass in a plain object. I did fix a small typo tho, my UK spellcheck is converting `background-color` to `background-colour`

Answer (score 0):

The object key should be changed to zIndex as should your backgroundColor..
Any dashed names should be camelcased.

Comment: the way I set it works correctly, what it is not working is this: .css({
    'background-colour': '#ddf8dd',
    'z-index': 200 .... this is not showing the background color correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:contains("Yesss")').closest('tr').css({
 'background-color': 'red',
 'z-index':'200'
})
```

this will work if tr position absolute